# referential actions with trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, referential

I have this task to emulate a referential action with a trigger. The task itself is: **Give an example of how to use a trigger to emulate a referential action.**

I know hot to use triggers and referential actions but combined I just don't really get it, and the question itself.

Comment: By "referential action" do they mean "foreign key constraint"?

Comment: they mean one of these `ON DELETE CASCADE` , `... SET NULL` , etc... for `foreign keys`

Comment: OK so for example `ON DELETE CASCADE` simply means: when a row is deleted from this table, also delete any dependent rows from child tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the least objectionable of the options you listed is to do a cascading delete when a parent row is removed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER DELETE ON parent_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM child_table
   WHERE parent_id = :old.parent_id;

  <<repeat for each child table>>
END;
```

Comment: So I basically had to simulate the referential action through basic logical statements.
That is what I needed to understand. Thank you!